# Unable to make a tab completion file for MacPorts in Bash?

Tags: macos, bash, tab-completion

I did not find by Google a tab completion file for MacPorts.
It should not apparetnly differ much from the ones for Git and Django.

**How can you make a tab completion for MacPorts in Bash?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can install the port `bash-completion`, as noted [here](http://trac.macports.org/wiki/howto/bash-completion).