# Unable to have MacPorts' tab completion in Zsh

Tags: macos, zsh, macports, tab-completion

I get the following in including [MacPorts' Bash tab completion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764476/unable-to-make-a-tab-completion-file-for-macports-in-bash) to Zsh

```
/opt/local/etc/bash_completion:[:48: unrecognized condition: `2'
[ -- cut -- ]
/opt/local/etc/bash_completion:[:62: unrecognized condition: `2'
/opt/local/etc/bash_completion:69: command not found: shopt
[ -- cut -- ]
/opt/local/etc/bash_completion:3015: command not found: complete
/opt/local/etc/bash_completion:3062: parse error near `&&'
```

**How can you have MacPorts' tab completion in Zsh?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might want to try [zsh completion](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/zsh_19.html) for zsh. `bash_completion` is for Bash, surprisingly enough.

**edit** It sounds like you might be looking specifically for completion support for the `port` command. It looks like the MacPorts `zsh` package has a `+mp_completion` variant that will install completion for the `port` command:

```
sudo port install zsh +mp_completion
```

Comment: @Brian: Thank you! I completely forgot that there is the command variant in MacPorts. It seems that I cannot survive without tab completions :) Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Note if you don't want to use MacPorts’ version of zsh, there is a separate `zsh-completions` port, then you just add `/opt/local/share/zsh/site-functions` to your `$fpath` and you get MacPorts completion (plus a bunch of others).

Answer (score 1):

Waking up that old question I just found doing some researchs to mention the wonderful [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) utility intended for OSX that brings easily tab completion to port amongst others and also many many other nice stuff. A must have imho :)

Comment: I use oh-my-zsh and I did not have `port` completion until I installed the `zsh-completions` port mentioned by Nicholas Riley.